# Passing Json to the Web Service

Tags: c#, json, web-services, rest

I'm trying to push json data to the webservice;

Here is my sample data;

```
    {
       "data" : {
       "username" : "demo",
       "password" : "demo1082*098/*42a", 
       "LoginToken" :     "AAFF540EC55DASEFBE7E3D8404AED31F6DD30CA2BFCE2433B9475E696GG38730"
       }
    }
```

Here is my webservice;

```
public string Post([FromBody]string data)
List<Login> datas = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Login>>(data);
```

Error; An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code

Data appears as NULL

I'm using WebAPI, restful api, C#, visual std 2015

Thanks in Advance.

EDIT;

I'm using DHC chrome extention to POST data.
HEADER;
Content-Type: application/json
BODY;

```
{
           "data" : {
           "username" : "demo",
           "password" : "demo1082*098/*42a", 
           "LoginToken" :     "AAFF540EC55DASEFBE7E3D8404AED31F6DD30CA2BFCE2433B9475E696GG38730"
           }
        }
```

Error;

500 Internal Server Error

EDIT;
I fount the error which is beacause of "string" kind of data. I solved the problem when I change it as "dynamic". Can someone recommend me a keyword instead of dynamic ?

Comment: please share how do you pass value to web service, code

Comment: @IkramTurgunbaev thank you. I'm using POST method.

Comment: @NewPHPer check my solution, its just another way to do it, in case you want to avoid dynamic key word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You have to create a class like

```
public class LoginData
{
    public string username {get;set;}
    public string password {get;set;}
    public string LoginToken {get;set;}
}
```

and in your web service use like following

```
public string Post([FromBody]LoginData data)
```

2) I seen following line that you already created a class name `Login` (if you have single record in json)

```
Login datas = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Login>(data);
```

So you also can use

```
public string Post([FromBody]Login data)
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to do it as follows,

Create class of your request

```
    public class Data
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string LoginToken { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Data data { get; set; }
}
```

and in your post method

```
public string Post([FromBody]RootObject data)
```

Now you even don't have to deserialise it. and can access direct as property of class.

Comment: can i know the reason of down vote, is there an improvement require

Comment: I voted it up. Your answer worked for me. Thank you.